# Simple UDP server reply not working

Tags: c, sockets, udp, server

Right now I'm just trying to get my "server" to reply back immediately after receiving a UDP datagram(in preparation for more complicated stuff).

However, I keep getting a Invalid Argument error on the sendTo (at RunTime).  Can anyone help point out why?  I have written other sendTo's and looked at sample code on the Internet and cannot pinpoint why.

The recvfrom is working fine.

Thanks!

```
void *receive(void *socket)
{
    int* socket_ptr = (int *) socket;
    int socket_desc = *socket_ptr;

    int recv_length;

    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof (struct sockaddr_in);
    while(1){

             struct Message msg;
             struct sockaddr_in * incoming = malloc (sizeof (struct sockaddr_in));

             if ((recv_length = recvfrom (socket_desc, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0,
                 (struct sockaddr *) incoming, &addrlen))
                  == -1)
             {
             }else
             {

                  struct CoordMessage * cm = malloc(sizeof (struct CoordMessage));
                  cm->msgID = BEGINSUCCESS;
                  cm->tid = msg.tid;

                   if (sendto(socket_desc, cm, sizeof(struct CoordMessage), 0, (struct sockaddr *) incoming, sizeof(incoming)) < 0){
                           perror("TEMP Send failed ");
                           exit(1);
                   }
             }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof(incoming)` in the `sendto` call is just the size of a pointer, you need to pass the sizeof the struct that you got from the `recvfrom` call. Also the `malloc` is causing a memory leak, because you never `free` the memory.

I suggest declaring the struct as

```
struct sockaddr_in incoming = {0};
```

and then passing the address of the struct to `recvfrom` and `sendto`, e.g.

```
if ((recv_length = recvfrom (socket_desc, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0,
    (struct sockaddr *) &incoming, &addrlen))
     == -1)
```

and

```
if (sendto(socket_desc, cm, sizeof(struct CoordMessage), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &incoming, addrlen) < 0)
```

The same thing applies to the `cm` variable, if you `malloc` it, you need to `free` it. But you could just declare it, and pass the address.

Comment: thanks, it was the sizeof that fixed it.  Definitely agree with the malloc and free statements.  This code was actually more of a POC to get the reply working so the mallocs and lack of frees wont stay this way.  Thanks again!